# r: geom_jitter() width argument with discrete x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot scatterplot with a discrete x-axis (Male / Female) whose points I'd like to jitter using `geom_jitter`. It seems, though, that with discrete axis like this—geom_jitter will just not plot points if they jitter "off" of the axis (which is easy given a discrete axis w/ two labels).

Instead, what I'd like is a jitter of a certain *length*. For example, the data in the "Male" category and "Female" category would be restricted to a column (the width of the jitter); I don't want the jitter's width to refer to actual x-axis values.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

(I know about things like `facet_grid` and other ways of separating data; I'm not looking for different ways of separating things, I'd like specifically to use `geom_jitter` (or something that jitters data) with a discrete x-axis)

Comment: It's always easier with an example!

Comment: You can use `geom_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0.5)` and so on to set the amount of jittering even with character or factor data, is there some reason the width and height manually won't work for you?